# How to encrypt text with a password in python?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

Surprisingly difficult to find a straight answer to this on Google.

I'm wanting to collect a piece of text and a message from a user such as `1PWP7a6xgoYx81VZocrDr5okEEcnqKkyDc` `hello world`.

Then I want to be able to encrypt/decrypt the message with the text somehow so that I can save it in my database and not worry about the data being exposed if my website gets hacked,
`encrypt('1PWP7a6xgoYx81VZocrDr5okEEcnqKkyDc', 'hello world')`
`decrypt('1PWP7a6xgoYx81VZocrDr5okEEcnqKkyDc', <encrypted_text>)`

Is there a simple way to achieve this with python and please can someone provide/direct me to an example.

Perhaps an example of how to create public/private key pairs using a seed such as `'1PWP7a6xgoYx81VZocrDr5okEEcnqKkyDc'`?

Many thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Just to be clear I'm looking for a way to encrypt my users data in a determanistic way not obfuscate the message.

If that means I have to generate a PGP/GPG pub/pri key pair on the fly by using the text `1PWP7a6xgoYx81VZocrDr5okEEcnqKkyDc` as a seed then that's fine but what's the method to do this?

Comment: "encrypt my users data in a determanistic way" - not secure. If every encryption of the same plaintext produces the same ciphertext, it'll be really easy to spot identical plaintexts in your database.

Comment: @user2357112 I'll be using a unique text string to encrypt each message so there will be no identical plaintexts.

Comment: Even if it isn't an exact duplicate, the other question seems to contain useful answers. Several of the answers to the other question use strong algorithms such as AES or DES. The essence of that question isn't obfuscation rather than security (even though OP was more interested in obfuscation). An adequate answer seems to be to use `pycrypto` for the encryption itself and  perhaps `base64` to get a string representation of the result.

Comment: @JohnColeman on closer inspection I think you are correct, thank you :)

Comment: @JohnColeman: Even if there are useful pieces, unless you already know what you're doing, it's impossible to recognize which ones are useful and how to use them properly. DES is broken, the top AES answer uses ECB mode, and the AES answer after it doesn't demonstrate proper IV handling. The accepted answer uses the freaking Vigenere cipher, broken for centuries and breakable by hand.

Comment: @user2357112 what's the issue with ECB mode?

Comment: @derrend: Identical plaintext blocks map to identical ciphertext blocks, so you get things like the [ECB penguin](https://www.google.com/search?q=ecb+penguin).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to encode a string according to a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password)

Comment: @Basj Just make sure that your input (key, iv, ciphertext) is bytes.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here's how to do it properly in CBC mode, including PKCS#7 padding:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random

def encrypt(key, source, encode=True):
    key = SHA256.new(key).digest()  # use SHA-256 over our key to get a proper-sized AES key
    IV = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)  # generate IV
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    padding = AES.block_size - len(source) % AES.block_size  # calculate needed padding
    source += bytes([padding]) * padding  # Python 2.x: source += chr(padding) * padding
    data = IV + encryptor.encrypt(source)  # store the IV at the beginning and encrypt
    return base64.b64encode(data).decode("latin-1") if encode else data

def decrypt(key, source, decode=True):
    if decode:
        source = base64.b64decode(source.encode("latin-1"))
    key = SHA256.new(key).digest()  # use SHA-256 over our key to get a proper-sized AES key
    IV = source[:AES.block_size]  # extract the IV from the beginning
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    data = decryptor.decrypt(source[AES.block_size:])  # decrypt
    padding = data[-1]  # pick the padding value from the end; Python 2.x: ord(data[-1])
    if data[-padding:] != bytes([padding]) * padding:  # Python 2.x: chr(padding) * padding
        raise ValueError("Invalid padding...")
    return data[:-padding]  # remove the padding
```

It's set to work with `bytes` data, so if you want to encrypt strings or use string passwords make sure you `encode()` them with a proper codec before passing them to the methods. If you leave the `encode` parameter to `True` the `encrypt()` output will be base64 encoded string, and `decrypt()` source should be also base64 string.

Now if you test it as:

```
my_password = b"secret_AES_key_string_to_encrypt/decrypt_with"
my_data = b"input_string_to_encrypt/decrypt"

print("key:  {}".format(my_password))
print("data: {}".format(my_data))
encrypted = encrypt(my_password, my_data)
print("\nenc:  {}".format(encrypted))
decrypted = decrypt(my_password, encrypted)
print("dec:  {}".format(decrypted))
print("\ndata match: {}".format(my_data == decrypted))
print("\nSecond round....")
encrypted = encrypt(my_password, my_data)
print("\nenc:  {}".format(encrypted))
decrypted = decrypt(my_password, encrypted)
print("dec:  {}".format(decrypted))
print("\ndata match: {}".format(my_data == decrypted))
```

your output would be similar to:

```
key:  b'secret_AES_key_string_to_encrypt/decrypt_with'
data: b'input_string_to_encrypt/decrypt'

enc:  7roSO+P/4eYdyhCbZmraVfc305g5P8VhDBOUDGrXmHw8h5ISsS3aPTGfsTSqn9f5
dec:  b'input_string_to_encrypt/decrypt'

data match: True

Second round....

enc:  BQm8FeoPx1H+bztlZJYZH9foI+IKAorCXRsMjbiYQkqLWbGU3NU50OsR+L9Nuqm6
dec:  b'input_string_to_encrypt/decrypt'

data match: True
```

Proving that same key and same data still produce different ciphertext each time.

Now, this is much better than ECB but... if you're going to use this for communication - don't! This is more to explain how it should be constructed, not really to be used in a production environment and especially not for communication as its missing a crucial ingredient - message authentication. Feel free to play with it, but you should not roll your own crypto, there are well vetted protocols that will help you avoid the common pitfalls and you should use those.

Comment: 'there are well vetted protocols that will help you avoid the common pitfalls and you should use those' you mean there is a simpler/more robust way to achieve this? if so could you please link me to it?

Comment: Not this thing specifically - it depends on your application. If you want to communicate TLS 1.2 is pretty robust for pretty much all your communication needs over almost any protocol (TLS doesn't need to be used on the transport layer only) and `OpenSSL` has you fully covered there. If not sure what's your best bet, you can ask a question on [crypto.se] and people ought to be able to shine some light on your path to cryptography :)

Comment: In the comments here - https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17044/1427 - Damon argues that the IV should be concatenated with the plaintext before encryption. I've only decrypted KeyWrap / ECB which didn't need the IV to decrypt; does CBC mode actually need it? Because @derrend here says they want to encrypt the same plaintext over and over, so the argument for using the IV as the first block to make the first block different every time sounds good to my not-cryptographer ears, but .. is it?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - yes, CBC actually needs it, and if it's not random and unique (to the key used) CBC becomes susceptible to multitude of attacks. As for Damon's comments, I'm afraid he doesn't know what he's talking about - in CBC mode, IV is used to XOR the first 'plaintext' block, and since it's a chaining mode if you can't retrieve the first block you cannot retrieve any other - meaning, if you encrypt your IV with the data there is no way to decrypt it. There is a way to obfuscate your IV but that exceeds the comment section size and, besides, there is absolutely no reason to do it.

Comment: The code is not working for me, I get the exception `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'` while decrypting. Solution is to put `padding = ord(data[-1])` instead of `padding = data[-1]` .

Comment: @joanlofe - oops, forgot to account for that one in the Python 2.x mods, thanks for catching it.

Comment: **Warning**: using SHA as derivation method for the key (a KBKDF) is fine for input strings with *very high amount of entropy* but not for normal passwords or phrases. CBC is fine for storage in place (e.g. in a database) but **not** for transport mode security: rely on TLS instead.

Comment: This might be a great solution, but it looks unnecessarily complicated. I see no reason not to use the `cryptography` library (https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) which encrypts/decrypts in one line of code. The package is statically linked so all dependencies are included.

Comment: why do you recommend against using this for communication ?

Comment: @Ferris - because rolling your own crypto is, usually, a bad idea. In particular, using just this to secure data in transit would make your protocol susceptible to replay attacks, keystream substitution, padding oracle attacks and possibly other attacks. Furthermore, as previously noted in the comments, it doesn't include a safe key derivation for low-entropy data so it's susceptible to brute force attacks. There are whole groups of smarter people than me who spent decades to iron out the details so, for production use, please refer to their vetted protocols—like the TLS.

Answer (score 11):

Based on zwer's answers but shows an example attempt to deal with the case where the source text is exactly a multiple of 16 (`AES.block_size`). However @zwer explains in a comment how this code will **BREAK THE ENCRYPTION** of your text by not padding your source text appropriately, making your pipeline insecure.

Code:

```
from builtins import bytes
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random

def encrypt(string, password):
    """
    It returns an encrypted string which can be decrypted just by the 
    password.
    """
    key = password_to_key(password)
    IV = make_initialization_vector()
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    # store the IV at the beginning and encrypt
    return IV + encryptor.encrypt(pad_string(string))

def decrypt(string, password):
    key = password_to_key(password)   
    
    # extract the IV from the beginning
    IV = string[:AES.block_size]  
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    
    string = decryptor.decrypt(string[AES.block_size:])
    return unpad_string(string)

def password_to_key(password):
    """
    Use SHA-256 over our password to get a proper-sized AES key.
    This hashes our password into a 256 bit string. 
    """
    return SHA256.new(password).digest()

def make_initialization_vector():
    """
    An initialization vector (IV) is a fixed-size input to a cryptographic
    primitive that is typically required to be random or pseudorandom.
    Randomization is crucial for encryption schemes to achieve semantic 
    security, a property whereby repeated usage of the scheme under the 
    same key does not allow an attacker to infer relationships 
    between segments of the encrypted message.
    """
    return Random.new().read(AES.block_size)

def pad_string(string, chunk_size=AES.block_size):
    """
    Pad string the peculirarity that uses the first byte
    is used to store how much padding is applied
    """
    assert chunk_size  <= 256, 'We are using one byte to represent padding'
    to_pad = (chunk_size - (len(string) + 1)) % chunk_size
    return bytes([to_pad]) + string + bytes([0] * to_pad)
def unpad_string(string):
    to_pad = string[0]
    return string[1:-to_pad]

def encode(string):
    """
    Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode 
    binary data that needs be stored and transferred over media that are 
    designed to deal with textual data.
    This is to ensure that the data remains intact without 
    modification during transport.
    """
    return base64.b64encode(string).decode("latin-1")

def decode(string):
    return base64.b64decode(string.encode("latin-1"))
```

Tests:

```
def random_text(length):
    def rand_lower():
        return chr(randint(ord('a'), ord('z')))
    string = ''.join([rand_lower() for _ in range(length)])
    return bytes(string, encoding='utf-8')

def test_encoding():
    string = random_text(100)
    assert encode(string) != string
    assert decode(encode(string)) == string

def test_padding():
    assert len(pad_string(random_text(14))) == 16
    assert len(pad_string(random_text(15))) == 16
    assert len(pad_string(random_text(16))) == 32

def test_encryption():
    string = random_text(100)
    password = random_text(20)
    assert encrypt(string, password) != string
    assert decrypt(encrypt(string, password), password) == string
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir :)
@zwer would you please mind taking a moment to review if this new answer does indeed improve on your previous answer and cover use cases in which the source is a multiple of 16? Thanks you :)

Comment: @derrend - sorry for the delay, SO failed to notify me of your comment and I just noticed it. There's no bug in my example pertaining to the source size - when it's exactly a multiply of `AES.block_size` it returns `AES.block_size` as padding ensuring that PKCS#7 padding is present as per [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-10.3). Ignacio's `(chunk_size - (len(string) + 1)) % chunk_size` will, however, return zero padding for all multiples of `AES.block_size - 1` (15 bytes in this case) which **will break** the encryption/decryption process for sources of that size.

Comment: @zwer much appreciated sir, thank you very much for the response and clarification :)
Ignacio, your effort is still very much appreciated also.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the issue. let me know if you want me to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are going to use mentioned database to authorise users, you should use [hashes](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) or message digests of user's passwords, instead of 2 way encryption algorithms, that would make your data hard to use even in case of db leakage.
2. You cannot use above method to protect data that needs to be decrypted at some point, but even then you can use more secure way than just encrypting user passwords using some fixed key (which is the worst method). Take a look at [OWASP's Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).

As you wrote "I want to be able to encrypt/decrypt the message", I'm attaching a simple python source (tested under 2.7) for encr/decr using Blowfish.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish     # pip install pycrypto

BS = 8
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS) 
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

def doEncrypt(phrase, key):
    c1  = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
    return c1.encrypt(pad(phrase))

def doDecrypt(phrase, key):
    c1  = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
    return unpad(c1.decrypt(phrase))

def testing123(phrase, key):
    encrypted = doEncrypt(phrase, key)
    decrypted = doDecrypt(encrypted, key)
    assert phrase == decrypted, "Blowfish ECB enc/dec verification failed"
    print ("Blowfish ECB enc/dec verified ok")
    print ('phrase/key(hex)/enc+dec: {}/{}/{}'.format(phrase, key.encode('hex'), decrypted))

if __name__== "__main__":
    phrase= 'Ala ma kota, a kot ma AIDS.'
    key= os.urandom(32)
    testing123(phrase, key)
```

Comment: ECB? Blowfish? Insecure!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using two of the built-in functions on the standard Python library. The first one is the function **ord( )**, which takes a unicode string character as single input parameter and converts it to its corresponding unicode code (an integer). Two simple examples of the usage of this function are provided:

```
>>> ord('a')
    97

>>> ord('b')
    98
```

Then, you also have the inverse function of ord(): **chr( )**. And as you can imagine it works all the way around: it has a unicode code as an input (integer) and gets the corresponding unicode character (string):

```
>>> chr(97)
    'a'

>>> chr(98)
    'b'
```

Then you can do a simple encription by adding or substracting by some arbitrary integer... in this case, the number 2:

NOTE: Watch out in not utting very big values or you'll get an error id you reach a negative nber, for example.

```
def encrypt(message):
    newS=''
    for car in message:
        newS=newS+chr(ord(car)+2)
    return newS


print(encrypt('hello world'))
```

And getting as a result:

```
jgnnq"yqtnf
```

Now you can copy and past the same function and generate the decrypt function. In this case, it requires, obviously, to substract by 2:

```
def decrypt(message):
    newS=''
    for car in message:
        newS=newS+chr(ord(car)-2)
    return newS


print(decrypt('jgnnq"yqtnf'))
```

And the result will be the original message again:

```
'hello world'
```

This would be a great way to encrypt messages to non programmers. However, anyone with a little of programming knowledge could write a program that varied the integer we used until they found we have just added (2) to the unicode characters to encrypt the code...

In order to avoid that, I would propose two more complex alternatives.

**1.** The first one is the simplest: it consists in applying a different sum value to the chr function depending on the position of the character (for example, adding 2 to each unicode code when it occupies an even position in the string and substracting 3 when sits on an odd position).

**2.** The second one will generate the maximum security. It will consist on adding or substracting every unicode code for a number that will be randomly generated for each character. It will require to store an array of values to decript back the message. Make sure, then, this array of values is not available to third parties.

There it goes a possible solution for **1**.:

```
def encryptHard(message):
newS=''
for i in range(len(message)):
  if i%2==0:
    newS=newS+chr(ord(message[i])+2)
  else:
    newS=newS+chr(ord(message[i])-3)
return newS


print(encryptHard('hello world'))
```

And the result would be:

```
jbniqyltif
```

With the information hereby privided the decrypting script is obvious, so I won't bother you with coping, pasing and changing two values.

Finally, let's go into an in-depth-analysis of the second more complex alternative. With this one we can say that the encription will be almost indefitable. The idea is to vary the value we add or substract to each unicode code by a random number comprized between 0 and 255 (this is the range of numbers the chr( ) function admits, so do not try to play with other numbers o you will definitely get an error).

In this case, my proposal also randomizes the operation (sum or subtract), and avoids that the final number be a 0 (i.e. we would get an original character). Finally, its also returns a list with the numers it has been subtracted to, something you will need in order to decrypt the message back.

The chances that you get the same encrypted message if you call two times this function using the same message of length **n** are somewhat near to **255^n**... So don't worry (I say somewhat, as the algorithm created would actually generate more repeated values on the low-end or high-end range of values, for example, in case the most frequent characters were not centered in this distrubution unicode caracrer set (from 0 to 255), which is the case. However, the program, though not perfect, works flawlessly and protects the information.

```
import random as r
def encryptSuperHard(message):
  newS=''
  l_trans=[]
  for car in message:
    code=ord(car)
    add_subtract=r.choice([True,False])
    if add_subtract:
      transpose=r.randint(0,code-1)
      newS=newS+chr(code-transpose)
      l_trans=l_trans+[-transpose]
    else:
      transpose=r.randint(code+1,255)
      newS=newS+chr(code+transpose)
      l_trans=l_trans+[transpose]
  return newS, l_trans

print(encryptSuperHard('hello world'))
```

In this case, this random encrypting script I've made has returned this two value tuple, where the first value is the encrypted message and the second one is the value that has "transposed" every character in order of apearance.

```
('A0ŤłY\x10řG;,à', [-39, -53, 248, 214, -22, -16,     226, -40, -55, -64, 124])
```

Decrypting, in this case would need to take the encrypred message and the list and proceed as follows:

```
def decryptSuperHard(encriptedS,l):
  newS=''
  for i in range(len(l)):
    newS=newS+chr(ord(encriptedS[i])-l[i])
  return newS

print(decryptSuperHard('A0ŤłY\x10řG;,à', [-39,-53,248,214,-22,-16,226,-40,-55,-64,124]))
```

And the results goes back to:

> hello world

```
print(deccryptSuperHard('A0ŤłY\x10řG;,à', [-39, -53, 248, 214, -22, -16,     226, -40, -55, -64, 124])
```

Comment: I appreciate the time and trouble you went to in order to create this answer but I'm quite sure this would be a terrible and severely insecure solution to my original question, having to store the array of values needed to decipher the text for instance is not realistic and introduces further complications. Thank you for trying though :)

Comment: Congratulations, you've just discovered a rolling Caesar cipher, 2 millennia later.

Comment: -1, it's pretty clear this is not secure. It would take most people an entire 15 minutes to reverse engineer this and decrypt anything used by this "encryption" algorithm.

Comment: @derrend, you're welcome. I am sorry the more complex solution I came up with is not feasible. I am not a computer scientist, nor a cybersecurity expert, but I thought It might generate some ideas. Thank you for your time reading it, I enjoyed thinking it!

Answer (score 0):

Have gou considered using the [cryptography package](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography)? Here’s a simple example using [Fernet](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md) encryption from their README:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(b"A secret message")
f.decrypt(token)
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835994/2972183), the following AES256-GCM solution is even safer, although it requires a nonce:

```
import secrets
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead import AESGCM

# Generate a random secret key (AES256 needs 32 bytes)
key = secrets.token_bytes(32)

# Encrypt a message
nonce = secrets.token_bytes(12)  # GCM mode needs 12 fresh bytes every time
ciphertext = nonce + AESGCM(key).encrypt(nonce, b"Message", b"")

# Decrypt (raises InvalidTag if using wrong key or corrupted ciphertext)
msg = AESGCM(key).decrypt(ciphertext[:12], ciphertext[12:], b"")
```

To install the cryptography package:

```
pip install cryptography
```

Cheers,
Cocco

Answer (score -2):

Here is my solution for anyone who may be interested:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES  # pip install pycrypto
import base64

def cypher_aes(secret_key, msg_text, encrypt=True):
    # an AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long
    # in this case we make sure the key is 32 bytes long by adding padding and/or slicing if necessary
    remainder = len(secret_key) % 16
    modified_key = secret_key.ljust(len(secret_key) + (16 - remainder))[:32]
    print(modified_key)

    # input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
    # we achieve this by adding padding if necessary
    remainder = len(msg_text) % 16
    modified_text = msg_text.ljust(len(msg_text) + (16 - remainder))
    print(modified_text)

    cipher = AES.new(modified_key, AES.MODE_ECB)  # use of ECB mode in enterprise environments is very much frowned upon

    if encrypt:
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(modified_text)).strip()

    return cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(modified_text)).strip()


encrypted = cypher_aes(b'secret_AES_key_string_to_encrypt/decrypt_with', b'input_string_to_encrypt/decrypt', encrypt=True)
print(encrypted)
print()
print(cypher_aes(b'secret_AES_key_string_to_encrypt/decrypt_with', encrypted, encrypt=False))
```

Result:

```
b'secret_AES_key_string_to_encrypt'
b'input_string_to_encrypt/decrypt '
b'+IFU4e4rFWEkUlOU6sd+y8JKyyRdRbPoT/FvDBCFeuY='

b'secret_AES_key_string_to_encrypt'
b'+IFU4e4rFWEkUlOU6sd+y8JKyyRdRbPoT/FvDBCFeuY=    '
b'input_string_to_encrypt/decrypt'
```

Comment: Do not use ECB mode. Ever! It's not frowned upon in enterprise environments, it's frowned upon everywhere you want anything secure. ECB leaks so much data and is susceptible to so much attacks that some libraries refuse to even include it as an option.

Comment: Btw. here's how to use CBC (on files, but remove the file stream and you can use the same code for in-memory encryption as well): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44126075/7553525

Comment: @zwer I'm no python expert, would you possibly mind at all providing a modified example to achieve the same thing in a secure way using CBC? I'd appreciate it greatly :) I'll pay you 100 reputation points.

Comment: It would be quite easy if you used the same key on different pieces of data and/or different blocks of data, especially if the attacker has access to some of the plain text data to compare. While, technically, one can use ECB in a secure fashion, it's more trouble than it's worth so - ECB is like meth, not even once!

Comment: @zwer it is a different key each time but in some instances it is the same piece of text being encrypted, potentially hundreds of times :/

Comment: there you go, although the code can use a little clean-up as there are still vestigial structures from the code of the other question's OP...

Comment: @zwer much appreciated, i'll review the code and issue your reward shortly, thank you sir :)

Comment: I've greatly simplified it in the meantime - since you have all the data upfront there's no need to deal with streaming the data in so everything can be accomplished through simple slicing...

Comment: @zwer thanks again. Just a quick question, you mention to use encode() and decode() but i'm throwing the 'b' before the strings and it seems to be working fine. Is that ok?

Comment: No, you should not strip 'b' in front of `bytes` type (`str` on Python 2.x) - you can badly represent binary data that way - you should use `encode()/decode()` when turning bytes into strings and vice versa. I've updated the code a bit more so now by default `encrypt()` will produce a string, and will `decrypt()` will expect a string, but it will still expect bytes for the key and the data itself. There's a also a disclaimer how to do it if working with string-only data.

Comment: @zwer awsome, good to know thanks. You'll get your bounty in 21 hours apparently ;)

Comment: @zwer - AES KeyWrap uses ECB - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5649 - section 4.1. 2) says so. Is AES KeyWrap frowned upon? It's used by Apple on iOS devices and on LUKS and TrueCrypt to protect keys for encrypting filesystems, apparently - https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40073/1427 comments.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - KeyWrap never encrypts the same block, nor uses the same key over multiple blocks, hence ECB is perfectly fine there - however that's due to the wrapping design itself, not because ECB as a mode for a general encryption is a good idea. Besides, you might as well call it 'Joe' instead of ECB as it refers to the default mode of operation for block chains and it will never disappear - but library creators are trying to make it more and more difficult to use by end users as it's so easy to go wrong with it.