# Python logging module encrypt

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, encryption

I've got a python script with logging. Now I want to encrypt log with AES using pycrypto.

```
import logging
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
aes = AES.new(cryptoKey)
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG) #  file name, not custom file
logging.info('text')
```

I want to use `base64.b64encode(aes.encrypt('#logging text#'))` before write it to log . What is a most estate way to do it?

Comment: You will have to think about how you distinguish multiple "lines" in the binary log file, because `\n` can also appear in the middle of the ciphertext of a single log message.

Comment: Good remark, thanks. I can use base64 instead of binary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a bit more to encryption than mere forwarding of data. I would suggest writing your own log formatter and setting it as a root formatter - that way no matter where you log from in your app, even parts not controlled by your code, it will always go through a layer of encryption. So, something like:

```
import base64
import logging
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random

class EncryptedLogFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    # make sure that the `key` is a byte stream on Python 3.x
    def __init__(self, key, fmt=None, datefmt=None):
        self._key = SHA256.new(key).digest()  # use SHA-256 for a proper-sized AES key
        super(EncryptedLogFormatter, self).__init__(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)

    def format(self, record):
        message = record.msg  # log message to encrypt, if any
        if message:  # no sense to encrypt empty log messages
            # on Python 3.x encode first: message = message.encode("utf-8")
            iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)  # we'll be using CBC so generate an IV
            cipher = AES.new(self._key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            # AES demands all blocks to be of `AES.block_size` so we have to pad the message
            # you can use any padding you prefer, I think PKCS#7 is the best option
            padding = AES.block_size - len(message) % AES.block_size
            # pad the message...
            message += chr(padding) * padding # Python 3.x: bytes([padding]) * padding
            message_enc = iv + cipher.encrypt(message)  # add iv and encrypt
            # finally, replace our plain-text message with base64 encoded encrypted one
            record.msg = base64.b64encode(message_enc).decode("latin-1")
        # you can do more here, even print out your own string but we'll just
        # pass it to the default formatter now that the message is encrypted
        # so that it can respect other formatting options.
        return super(EncryptedLogFormatter, self).format(record)
```

Then you can use it wherever you can change the logging formatter, i.e.:

```
import sys
import logging

# lets get the root logger
root = logging.getLogger()
root.handlers = []  # blank out the existing handlers

# create a new handler, file handler instead of stdout is perfectly fine
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
# now lets get to business
handler.setFormatter(EncryptedLogFormatter("Whatever key/pass you'd like to use",
                                           "[%(levelname)s] %(message)s"))
# lets add it to the root logger so it gets called by the rest of the app automatically
root.addHandler(handler)

# And lets see what happens:
logging.warn("Sensitive stuff, hide me!")
# [WARNING] NDKeIav5G5DtbaSPB4Y/DR3+GZ9IwmXKzVTua1tTuDZ7uMwxBAKTXgIi0lam2dOQ
# YMMV, the IV is random so every block will be different every time
```

You can of course encrypt levels, timestamps, pretty much anything from the `logging.LogRecord`, and you can output whatever format you prefer. When the time comes to read your logs, you just need to do the reverse - see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212550).

**UPDATE**: As per request, here's how to do the 'reverse' (i.e. decrypt the encrypted logs). First, lets create a few log entries for testing (continuing with the previous):

```
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # let's make sure we support all levels

logging.warn("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")
logging.info("Consectetur adipiscing elit.")
logging.debug("Sed do eiusmod tempor.")
```

Provided that the format remained the same (`[%(levelname)s] %(message)s`), this will result in a log like (of course, it will always be different due to the random IV):

```
[WARNING] LQMLkbx3YF7ra3e5ZLRj3p1mi2dwCOJe/GMfo2Xg8BBSZMDmZO75rrgoiy/6kqjf
[INFO] D+ehnsq1kWQi61AsLOBkqglXla7jgc2myPFaCGcfCRe6drk9ZmNl+M3UkKPWkDiU
[DEBUG] +rHEHkM2YHJCkIL+YwWI4FNqg6AOXfaBLRyhZpk8/fQxrXLWxcGoGxh9A2vO+7bq
```

To create a *reader* for such a log (file) we need to be aware of the format so we can differentiate encrypted from non-encrypted data. In this case, separating the parts is easy - each log entry is on a new line, the levels are not encrypted and the actual encrypted data is always separated by a whitespace from the actual log level. So, to put all that together we might construct something like:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

# make sure that the `key` is a byte stream on Python 3.x
def log_decryptor(key, stream):  # assume the stream can be iterated line-by-line
    key = SHA256.new(key).digest()  # same derivation as in the EncryptedLogFormatter
    for line in stream:
        if not line.strip():  # empty line...
            continue  # ignore it!
        level, stream = line.split(None, 1)  # split on log level and log data
        message_enc = base64.b64decode(stream.encode("latin-1"))  # decode the stream
        iv = message_enc[:AES.block_size]  # grab the IV from the beginning
        # decrypt the stream
        message = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv).decrypt(message_enc[AES.block_size:])
        padding = ord(message[-1])  # get the padding value; Python 3.x: message[-1]
        if message[-padding:] != chr(padding) * padding:  # verify the padding
            # on Python 3.x:     bytes([padding]) * padding
            raise ValueError("Invalid padding encountered.")
        # Python 3.x: decode the message: message[:-padding].decode("utf-8")
        yield "{} {}".format(level, message[:-padding])   # yield the decrypted value
```

And then you can use it as a regular generator to decrypt your logs, e.g.:

```
logs = ["[WARNING] LQMLkbx3YF7ra3e5ZLRj3p1mi2dwCOJe/GMfo2Xg8BBSZMDmZO75rrgoiy/6kqjf",
        "[INFO] D+ehnsq1kWQi61AsLOBkqglXla7jgc2myPFaCGcfCRe6drk9ZmNl+M3UkKPWkDiU",
        "[DEBUG] +rHEHkM2YHJCkIL+YwWI4FNqg6AOXfaBLRyhZpk8/fQxrXLWxcGoGxh9A2vO+7bq"]

for line in log_decryptor("Whatever key/pass you'd like to use", logs):
    print(line)

# [WARNING] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
# [INFO] Consectetur adipiscing elit.
# [DEBUG] Sed do eiusmod tempor.
```

Or if you've set your log to stream to a file, you can directly decrypt such file as:

```
with open("path/to/encrypted.log", "r") as f:
    for line in log_decryptor("Whatever key/pass you'd like to use", f):
        print(line)  # or write to a 'decrypted.log' for a more persistent solution
```

Comment: The `setFormatter` does not exist for python3 is there any alternative for that?

Comment: @MasoudR. - It should be fine on Python 3.x, too - nothing changed in the base structure according to the official Python docs: [`logging.Handler.setFormatter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setFormatter). I've just double-checked it and it works fine. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Thanks, I missed the logging. It works fine on Python3 but the message in `EncryptedLogFormatter` must be encoded.

Comment: Can you please add a decryption method too?

Comment: Unfortunately this example will fail if logged message includes formatting, e.g. `logging.debug("Sed do eiusmod %s.", "tempor")`, because subsequent formatting in parent class will be attempted using already encrypted format string.