# Python logging encrypt with custom format

Tags: python-3.x, logging, encryption, pycrypto

I'm trying to create a custom logger class for printing the log and save it to a file as encrypted at the same time. I used this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475816/python-logging-module-encrypt).
Here is my code:

```
import base64
import logging
from pprint import pprint
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256
from Cryptodome.Hash import MD5
from Cryptodome import Random


class logger:
    """
    Encrypt log messages to file as encrypted
    """
    class EncryptedLogFormatter(logging.Formatter):
        def __init__(self, key, fmt=None, datefmt=None):
            self._key = self.hash_gen(key, 16)
            super(logger.EncryptedLogFormatter, self).__init__(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)

        @staticmethod
        def hash_gen(key, size):
            """
            return a hash object of key base on size
            """
            key = MD5.new(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()  # use SHA-256 for a proper-sized AES key
            return key[:size]

        def format(self, record):
            # pprint(vars(record))
            message = record.msg  # log message to encrypt, if any
            asctime = record.asctime  # asctime to encrypt
            levelname = record.levelname  # levelname to encrypt

            if message:  # no sense to encrypt empty log messages
                iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)  # we'll be using CBC so generate an IV
                cipher = AES.new(self._key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
                # AES demands all blocks to be of `AES.block_size` so we have to pad the message
                # you can use any padding you prefer, I think PKCS#7 is the best option
                padding = AES.block_size - len(message) % AES.block_size
                # pad the message...
                message += chr(padding) * padding
                message_enc = iv + cipher.encrypt(message.encode())  # add iv and encrypt
                # finally, replace our plain-text message with base64 encoded encrypted one
                record.msg = base64.b64encode(message_enc).decode()

            if asctime:
                iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
                cipher = AES.new(self._key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
                padding = AES.block_size - len(asctime) % AES.block_size
                asctime += chr(padding) * padding
                asctime_enc = iv + cipher.encrypt(asctime.encode())
                record.asctime = base64.b64encode(asctime_enc).decode()

            if levelname:
                iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
                cipher = AES.new(self._key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
                padding = AES.block_size - len(levelname) % AES.block_size
                levelname += chr(padding) * padding
                levelname_enc = iv + cipher.encrypt(levelname.encode())
                record.levelname = base64.b64encode(levelname_enc).decode()

            return super(logger.EncryptedLogFormatter, self).format(record)

    def __init__(self, key, filename, level=logging.INFO, fmt='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(level)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        fh.setFormatter(logger.EncryptedLogFormatter(key, fmt, datefmt))
        root.addHandler(ch)
        root.addHandler(fh)

    def print(self, message):
        logging.info(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logg = logger("abcdefg", 'Some path')
    logg.print("Hello")
```

Console output:

> 2018-08-12 13:21:07:INFO: Hello

File output:

> 2018-08-12 13:21:07:QcMrG7d7gvxwiagidFozC2v4kQukgnbXv5Hs2rMDAZQ=: Px4ZlIE7usOTTtbURDjrGW4VBXaIKH/F3vhs9pj5G3o=

It seems that the `asctime` hasn't been encrypted.
What I want is to just use the user format and encrypt time, level and message. It would be better to just create the whole line encrypted but I don't know how to create the custom message for user input format.

Comment: What debugging have you done? One question would be: is it that asctime isn't set so the encryption is never done, or is it that the encrypted version is *replaced* by the parent? Have you considered getting the record from the parent *then* encrypting it?

Comment: you need to either encrypt the finale string after calling `super().format()` (and not before, since before that point the date isn't in string form and thus can't be encrypted) or just dont call `super().format()` at all and format the message youself

Comment: to clarify, you can't actually change asctime since it is determined by `record.created` every time you call `format()`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, with help of @AntiMatterDynamite I just encrypted the message before `super().format()` it was easier to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AntiMatterDynamite said, the whole message can be encrypted before `super().format()`:

```
import base64
import logging
from pprint import pprint
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256
from Cryptodome.Hash import MD5
from Cryptodome import Random


class logger:
    """
    Encrypt log messages to file as encrypted
    """
    class EncryptedLogFormatter(logging.Formatter):
        def __init__(self, key, fmt=None, datefmt=None):
            self._key = self.hash_gen(key, 16)
            super(logger.EncryptedLogFormatter, self).__init__(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)

        @staticmethod
        def hash_gen(key, size):
            """
            return a hash object of key base on size
            """
            key = MD5.new(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()  # use SHA-256 for a proper-sized AES key
            return key[:size]

        def format(self, record):
            # encrypt whole message instead of record.msg
            message = super().format(record)
            if message:  # no sense to encrypt empty log messages
                iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)  # we'll be using CBC so generate an IV
                cipher = AES.new(self._key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
                # AES demands all blocks to be of `AES.block_size` so we have to pad the message
                # you can use any padding you prefer, I think PKCS#7 is the best option
                padding = AES.block_size - len(message) % AES.block_size
                # pad the message...
                message += chr(padding) * padding
                message_enc = iv + cipher.encrypt(message.encode())  # add iv and encrypt
                # finally, replace our plain-text message with base64 encoded encrypted one
                return base64.b64encode(message_enc).decode()

    def __init__(self, key, filename, level=logging.INFO, fmt='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(level)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        fh.setFormatter(logger.EncryptedLogFormatter(key, fmt, datefmt))
        root.addHandler(ch)
        root.addHandler(fh)

    def print(self, message):
        logging.info(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    log = logger("abcdefg", 'Some path')
    log.print("Hello")
```