# Python 3.4 Encrypter and Decrypter not working

Tags: python, encryption

I'm writing a python program to encrypt and decrypt a custom string. This isn't going to be used for anything serious, it's just for fun. The encrypter seems to work fine, but here it is, the encrypter. The program writes everything to a file. As seen in the code below, the program loops through ASCII characters if the key (which is defined by the user) will put it above 127.

My issue is that when decrypting, I get some strange characters. It fails when using a key over 229.

Encrypter:

```
temp_key = 9999
message = "Hello"
result = ""
for char in message:
    ecry_char_int = ord(char) - temp_key
    while ecry_char_int < 0:
                temp_key -= 128
                ecry_char_int = 128 - temp_key
    result += chr(ecry_char_int)
print(result)
```

Decrypter:

```
result2 = ""
encoded = result
ekey = 9999
for char in encoded:
    decr_char_int = ord(char) + ekey
    while decr_char_int > 127:
         ekey -= 128
         decr_char_int = ekey
    result2 += chr(decr_char_int)
print(result2)
```

For example, encrypting `"Hello"` with the key `9999`; I get the encrypted string of `` "qV]]`" ``. Decrypting string `` "qV]]`" `` with key `9999` I get this:

```
'\x0fello'
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I'm supposed to stop this from happening, since it's only the first character this happens with.

Note: I don't want/know how to install any additional modules (i.e. Cryptography) since this is/was being mostly developed on my school computer.

Comment: Could you please provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you removed the strange ASCII code 15 character from the question and I can't re-add it with an edit because an edit has to be at least 6 characters.

Comment: @Hami: nothing was removed, only added to; see the "side-by-side markdown" diff at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44477022/revisions

Comment: @MartijnPieters here is a screenshot of what I see. Notice the strange character being removed: http://imgur.com/a/co8wD

Comment: @Hami: analysing the first revision source I can see it was there, but because it's not printable that's not very helpful. Better for the OP to use the `repr()` output instead, I'll add that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for fixing that!

Comment: @MartijnPieters @Hami I used the `repr()` thing in my code, and it still didn't work. I did this to the decryption part.
    `result2 += chr(decr_char_int)`
    `print(repr(result2))`

Comment: @AndrewMyerson: that was not meant to be a solution, only an aid to show what the contents of your variable are in a readable and reproducible fashion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah, I see.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not really encrypting anything - after the first character your algorithm turns into a simple Caesar cipher, where the first character will always be 'encrypted' as the value of `128 - temp_key % 128` for all conditions where `temp_key > ord(first_char)`.

The problem is that after the initial `ecry_char_int = ord(char) - temp_key`, you're not considering your current character for anything if it happens to be smaller than the key (and that's the case with `ord('H')` being `72` while your key is `9999`) - you go into a loop where you're successively subtracting 128 from the `temp_key` and while setting `128 - temp_key` as `ecry_char_int`. Eventually, `temp_key` will be small enough to produce a positive number when subtracted from `128` at which point you'll set that number as your 'encrypted' character. So, you essentially went a long, loopy way to set the first character to the value of `128 - temp_key % 128` (which is `113`, btw. and that's why the first character from your function will always be `q` for pretty much all keys `>256`).

But that's not all - since you've now modified the value of your `temp_key` to `temp_key % 128` of the original (so `15` for your `9999` key), now all the consequent characters will be ascii left-shifted by that amount resulting `e` to become `V` (`chr(ord("e") - 15)`) etc. Hence - you've got yourself a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Your decryption function does pretty much the same in the opposite direction, the first character will always be constructed the same way and the rest of the characters will be ascii right-shifted by the same position to their original places.

Do yourself a favor and use a proper encryption if you need encryption. Here's a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212550/7553525).