# ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long. KEY size makes no sense

Tags: python-3.x, aes

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt
import os
import hashlib
import base64
import sys
import socket, select


def hash(password):
    return hashlib.sha256(bytes(password, encoding= 'utf-8')).hexdigest()

def encrypt(raw_data):
    pad = lambda s: s + (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size) * chr(AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)
    raw_data = pad(raw_data)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    print(sys.getsizeof(iv)) #prints 49
    print(sys.getsizeof(KEY)) # prints 113, shouldn't this be 32 bytes (256 bits) ?
    cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, iv) # error occurs here
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw_data))



def decrypt(encrypted_text):
    unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s) -1:])]
    encrypted_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encrypted_text)
    iv = encrypted_text[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text[AES.block_size:]))







password="mypassword"

KEY = hash(password)


encrypt("some data to encrypt") #error when calling this function
```

Every time I do `print(sys.getsizeof(KEY))` the size is 113 no matter what the password is. Shouldn't this be 32 since I'm using sha256.

I believe this is the reason I'm getting this error but I'm not completely sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `sys.getsizeof()` is not how you get the length of a sequence.

Comment: Ah, well, regardless, do you know why exactly I'm getting this error with my current set up?

Comment: `>>> len(hashlib.sha256(b'').hexdigest())`
`64`

Comment: but where would I be passing the argument `password` ?

Comment: Irrelevant. It will *always* have a length of 64.

Comment: so with my current setup, how could I fix the error?

Comment: Use a key of length 16, 24, or 32. Try *not* getting the hex representation of the hash.

Comment: @TimalPeramune - use `digest()` not `hexdigest()` for your key. Check [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568262/how-to-encrypt-text-with-a-password-in-python/44212550#44212550) to see how to do it properly.

Comment: @zwer digest() works ! thanks!